# customized Xenial distro: better rebuild from scratch or upgrade from beta2?

Tags: 16.04

as *passim* I've told in some of my previous messages, I'm the maintainer of our customized LTS distro. In next few days Xenial will be released and I've already set-up a multilingual customized distro based on it (before beta1, now beta2 based), the way to get ready and don't have troubles when 16.04 will be officially released.

Now, the question is: as soon as Xenial will be officially released, it would be better rebuild it from scratch - i.e. starting from officially released iso - or it will be sufficient updating beta2, *mutatis mutandis* in sources.list? Or it will be the same?

Thanks for your time and cheers,

Silvia

Answer (score 0):

Beta ISOs were just that - beta ISOs.

Rebuild your ISOs after 16.04 officially releases.  You get kernel updates and other fixes that way.